# Loadiing a trained Word2Vec model in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word2vec

I am trying to load google's Pre-trained vectors 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz' [Google-word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) into spark.

I converted the bin file to txt and created a smaller chunk for testing that I called 'vectors.txt'. I tried loading it as the following:

```
      val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("Word2VecExample")
  .getOrCreate()

  val model2= Word2VecModel.load(sparkSession.sparkContext, "src/main/resources/vectors.txt")

  val synonyms = model2.findSynonyms("the", 5)

  for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {
    println(s"$synonym $cosineSimilarity")
  }
```

and to my surprise I am faced with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/elievex/Repository/ARCANA/src/main/resources/vectors.txt/metadata
```

I'm not sure where did the 'metadata' after 'vectors.txt' came from.
I am using Spark, Scala and Scala IDE for Eclipse.

What am I doing wrong? is there a different way to load a pre-trained model in spark? Would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly did you get vector.txt? If you read JavaDoc for [Word2VecModel.save](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2VecModel.html#save(org.apache.spark.SparkContext,%20java.lang.String)) you may see that:

> This saves: - human-readable (JSON) model metadata to path/metadata/ - Parquet formatted data to path/data/ 
>   
> The model may be loaded using Loader.load.

So what you need is model in [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) format which is standard for Spark ML models.

Unfortunately load from Google's native format has not been implemented yet (see [SPARK-9484](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9484)).